# How to get info from cursor return in another SP in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, select, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor

I want to call a SP from another SP that return one cursor 'n' times and use the cursor to read its information.

I have the following code for one SP in Oracle PL SQL:

```
create or replace procedure USP_FALTAN_REPORTE(cur_OUT out REF CURSOR) as
  vFaltantes_SP1      REF CURSOR
  vNumProyeto         NUMBER;
  vTemporalTable      NUMBER;
BEGIN
  DECLARE
    CURSOR proyectos is
      SELECT DISTINCT PROYECTO FROM TB_PROYECTOS;
  BEGIN
    FOR c1 in proyectos loop
      dbms_output.put_line('# proyecto: ' || c1.proyecto);
      vNumProyeto := c1.proyecto;       
      USP_FALTANTES(vNumProyeto , vFaltantes_SP1);
   end loop;
  end;
end;
```

My question is how I can get the info from the cursor vFaltantes_SP1 that is returned of the SP USP_FALTANTES ?

When I do the test to USP_FALTANTES this return a cursor of type ref cursor too.

I have tried with something like that:

```
BEGIN
   OPEN vFaltantes_SP1; 
      LOOP
       FETCH vFaltantes_SP1 BULK COLLECT
         INTO vTemporalTable;
        CLOSE vFaltantes_SP1;            
          dbms_output.put_line(vTemporalTable.First);
      END LOOP;
END;
```

But Oracle show this error:

> PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

The error is marked in OPEN vFaltantes_SP1;

Can someone help me.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the open cursor line, try this:

```
BEGIN
      LOOP
       FETCH vFaltantes_SP1 BULK COLLECT
         INTO vTemporalTable limit 1000;
      END LOOP;
        CLOSE vFaltantes_SP1;            
      for n in vTemporalTable.first .. vTemporalTable.last loop
             dbms_output.put_line(vTemporalTable(n));
      end loop;
END;
```